# Does using .clearProperties() of TextMessage interface (JMS) remove the properties from the heap space?

Tags: java, jms, heap-memory, mq

I have the following code:

```java
@JmsListener(...)
Public void messageListener(TextMessage message){
   System.out.println(message.getText());
   //Writing string to a file...and then
   //clear it from heap space
   message.clearProperties();
   //Once removed from heap read from file and process string
   processString();
}
```

Does this remove the `String` from heap space. Actually, the message I pick up from the MQ maybe 20MB so I want to write it to a file and then clear it from my heap space. Would this work? Please let me know how I can phrase the question better.

Comment: Why are you trying to "clear it from heap" instead of just letting the entire object get GC'd?

Comment: I am actually working with a memory constraint. The string as I said can reach 20MB. Moreover it's an XML string which I later try to parse. The parsing also uses some memory. I want to write the XML string to a file so that I can read from the file and parse the XML as and when I need. Should I set the ```message``` to null for GC to take care of it?

Comment: Once your messageListener completes that reference to the message disappears, so there is no point in setting the `message` parameter to null.

Comment: Hi tgdavies, so basically I have updated the question. I want to write the string to a file, then remove it from heap (because it's already on a file) and then selectively read from the file and process the string. After I process it then the messageListener method ends

Comment: If you really want to have the message garbage collected as soon as possible, it may be better to save the string in `messageListener` but process it asynchronously. Even if you set `message` to `null` as soon as you have saved the string, I expect a higher stack frame will still have a reference to it, so it won't be GCd until `messageListener` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JavaDoc for `javax.jms.Message.clearProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#clearProperties--) states:

> Clears a message's properties.
>
> The message's header fields and body are not cleared.

If the `String` you care about is retrieved using `javax.jms.Message.getText()` then that means the `String` is part of the **body** of the message which `clearProperties()` doesn't even touch.

In any event, the only thing that frees heap space is the garbage collector and you have no direct control over that. The best you can do is make sure the `Object` you are interested in has no references. However, in this situation you're working with an API (i.e. JMS) whose implementation is not clear so even doing something like setting `message = null` might not be sufficient for GC to collect it since the underlying implementation may still have references to it.

Using `javax.jms.Message.clearBody()` would seem more appropriate for you use-case, but even then the JMS API makes no guarantee that the underlying message data would be free for garbage collection. The exact behavior would depend entirely on the JMS implementation you were using.

Comment: Hi Justin
Thank you so much for taking time to answer. How about if I use the clearBody() function? Would this clear the string object?

Comment: What if I just clear the body so the message object is now practically empty and therefore takes up less memory. Even if the underlying implementation has reference to the message object, the message object itself will be almost empty as I cleared its body and properties. Would this reduce the overall memory usage ? I don't mind if the message objects exists as long as it doesn't take up lot of space

Comment: Like I said, it depends on your JMS implementation. Calling `clearBody()` may not actually free the underlying data structure(s) for garbage collection.

Comment: Hi Bertram
What kind of JMS implementation would free up the underlying data structures? While your answer is very descriptive I would like to know what sort of JMS implementation can help free up the underlying data structures.  Also I am very sorry for the late reply!

Comment: There is no "kind" of JMS implementation that would fit this requirement. You'd just have to look at the source code and see how `javax.jms.TextMessage` is implemented to know if invoking `clearBody` would free up the data for garbage collection. Of course, many JMS implementations are not open source. Even if you found a JMS implementation that fit this requirement it could change in the future since the JMS API makes no guarantees about this. Generally speaking, it's bad to rely on implementation details such as this would be.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234866/discussion-between-cs2899-and-justin-bertram).